# Eclipse gives an error 'Function 'MessageBoxA' could not be resolved' but still compiles successfully?

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi, user-interface, mingw

While compile Win32 applications on eclipse using the MinGW toolchain (and Internal Builder), eclipse compiles the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
int WinMain (HINSTANCE p1, HINSTANCE p2, LPSTR p3, int p4)
{
    MessageBox(0, "Hello.", "MyProg", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

But MessageBox is underlined in red, with the error: 'Function 'MessageBoxA' could not be resolved'. The same error is shown for SendMessage(). The program works OK, but I cant figure out why the red line is there. :@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse can't resolve WinAPI functions. You need to add folders with WinAPI headers (`windows.h`) in to [Include paths](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm).

Comment: It's just letting me add folder, not files. Should I add it to the indexer ?

Comment: Yes, add all folders with WinAPI headers and refresh whole project. This would be enough for resolving `MessageBox`, `SendMessage` and other WinAPI functions.