# getaddrinfo() could not be resolved winsock

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock, getaddrinfo

I'm having problems getting winsock to work, I'm just baffled and don't really know what to try next.

the `getaddrinfo(NULL)` is just there to show that it recognizes what arguments `getaddrinfo` should have but it still says it can't resolve it..

When I try to compile it in command line and add some error flags, this is what I get:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o test2.exe C:\Users\David\
workspace\vmulti\Debug\test2.o -lws2_32 -lmingw32
g++: warning: C:\Users\David\workspace\vmulti\Debug\test2.o: linker input file un
used because linking not done
```

Here's the error the compiler throws at me, I'm compiling with mingw:

```
Function 'getaddrinfo' could not be resolved    test.cpp        /vmulti line 48  Semantic Error
Function 'getaddrinfo' could not be resolved    test.cpp        /vmulti line 50 Semantic Error
too few arguments to function 'int getaddrinfo(const char*, const char*, const addrinfo*, addrinfo**)'  test.cpp        /vmulti line 48 C/C++ Problem
```

Here's the code:

**ws2tcpip.h:**

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
void WSAAPI freeaddrinfo (struct addrinfo*);
int WSAAPI getaddrinfo (const char*,const char*,const struct addrinfo*,
                    struct addrinfo**);
int WSAAPI getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr*,socklen_t,char*,DWORD,
                   char*,DWORD,int);
#else
/* FIXME: Need WS protocol-independent API helpers.  */
#endif
```

**test.cpp** (my program):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
using namespace std;

#define MYPORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to
#define BACKLOG 10     // how many pending connections queue will hold

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        WSADATA wsaData;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
                exit(1);
        }
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    int addr_size;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd, new_fd, len, numbytes;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

    getaddrinfo(NULL);  // Line 48

    if(getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &res) == -1); // Line 50
      cout << "Getaddrinfo error" << endl;
```

Comment: I've no idea what "*Function 'getaddrinfo' could not be resolved*" means, but make sure you're linking to `ws2_32.lib`. Regarding the last error, you're calling a function that takes 4 arguments with a single argument, so I don't know what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, i'm linking ws2_32.lib, the getaddrinfo(NULL) i just added to see if it would tell me the arguments are wrong(and thus actually finding the function while it tells me it cant)

Comment: The problem is, the error messages you posted are not output by any tool I'm familiar with, so I don't even know what "could not be resolved" means in this context.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and trying to get this working under windows, it seems i have linked ws2_32.lib correctly, if i remove it all hell breaks loose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202041/eclipse-gives-an-error-function-messageboxa-could-not-be-resolved-but-still). It looks like an error from Eplipse itself, not from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whey!  I'm two years late to the party.  But I've an answer for you & others in the same boat :D

It's not a bug in Eclipse, it's a bug in MinGW - right before freeaddrinfo/getaddrinfo/getnameinfo, the latest version of mingw's headers states:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP)
/**
 * For WIN2K the user includes wspiapi.h for these functions.
 */
```

... which makes no sense, because mingw doesn't include that header.

To fix:  I added forward declarations for the functions in my app & linked with ws2_32.lib as per usual.  My app was a simple 1-file app - it might make more sense to add this to your own header & include it where needed.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
   void WSAAPI freeaddrinfo( struct addrinfo* );

   int WSAAPI getaddrinfo( const char*, const char*, const struct addrinfo*,
                 struct addrinfo** );

   int WSAAPI getnameinfo( const struct sockaddr*, socklen_t, char*, DWORD,
                char*, DWORD, int );
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main() { /* ... */ }
```